# Calculate the sum of a list in python

Tags: python

I try to make this calculation quite simple 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 6^2 = 12
But I can't find the right function.
I tried to do it with sum

```
av = [1,2,3,6]
print(sum(av)**2)
```

But the result is not good because it makes (1+2+3+6)^2 = 144
Someone knows the solution to this problem please ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
print(sum([i**2 for i in av]))
```

I also note that in your original formula:

1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 6^2

Is NOT equal to 12... Have you explained your expectation right?

1 + 4 + 9 + 36 = 50

If you are looking to calculate the average of the square terms, then (taking advantage of Pavel's point below)...

```
print(sum(i**2 for i in av)/len(av))
```

Comment: Could also remove square brackets and make it a generator expression under `sum()`. This has a benefit of having O(1) memory complexity instead of O(n).

Comment: he is calculating average ie 50/4 = 12

Comment: Could indeed, good call Pavel.

Comment: @ArjunKumar, technically 12.5, still not 12.

Comment: @pavel yes, may be round-off

Comment: @ArjunKumar `print(int(sum(i**2 for i in av)/len(av)))` Maybe coverting it to `int` to round down to the nearest integer

Comment: yes, you're correct @ProChess